# Обмен переменными между модулями в pyton

Tags: python, python-3.x, модули, импорт

В моей программе есть два модуля. Из  `модуля(А)` я передаю переменную в `модуль(В)`, а из `модуля(В)` мне нужно вернуть переменную в `модуль(А)`.

Это не часть моей программы, а просто такой же пример.

**Модуль(А)**

```
import B

a = 4
y = B.y
x = 1

z = x + y

print(z)
```

**Модуль(В)**

```
import A
a = A.a

y = 3 + a
```

То есть мы переменную **`а`** передаем в `модуль В`, а из `модуля В` мы должны вернуть переменную **`y`**.

Возникает такая ошибка:

> partially initialized module 'B' has no attribute 'y' (most likely due to a circular import)

Подскажите пожалуйста, что я делаю не так и как это исправить?

Comment: Ну у вас действительно циклический импорт. Решения вам подсказали, да.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

**q1448874_a.py**

```
from q1448874_b import func_b


a = 4
y = func_b(a)

#y = B.y
x = 1
z = x + y

print(z)
```

**q1448874_b.py**

```
def func_b(A_a):
#    a = A_a
    y = 3 + A_a
    return y
```

Comment: Большое спасибо! Вы мне очень помогли.

Comment: @Serg пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0):

Самое простое решение - сделать третий модуль C, который будет содержать ваши глобальные переменные. И результаты вычислений A и B сохранять в C

Может есть более правильное решение?

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ!